# PHP MySQLi Match two table ID then redirects

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to match the ID of two tables then if the ID matched redirect it to specific page.

```
SELECT user_skill.user_id AS id_one, job_seeker.user_id AS id_two
FROM user_skill 
INNER JOIN job_seeker ON (user_skill.user_id = job_seeker.user_id)
```

> using this condition below

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if($fetch['id_one'] === $fetch['id_two']) {

            header('location: userhome.php');

        }
        else {

            header('location: userskill.php');

        }

     }

}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: J, what is your question? Does the query work? Is the redirect always to a certain page or is it based on the Ids?

Comment: The query works but I don't know what to do to make it compare the IDs and if they match use header('location')

Comment: What do you mean by "match the ID"? I mean you already joined the tables so the ID's are matched.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, what I want to happen is if the logged in user has already set up his skills it'll copy the user_id from job_seeker table to user_skill table so the next time they log in they won't need to set up their skills again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_skill.user_id AS id_one, job_seeker.user_id AS id_two
FROM user_skill 
INNER JOIN job_seeker ON (user_skill.user_id = job_seeker.user_id)
```

> using this condition below

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$variable=array($fetch['id_one']=>$fetch['id_two']);
 foreach($variable as $x=$value)
```

{
            if($x === $value) {

```
            header('location: userhome.php');

        }
        else {

            header('location: userskill.php');

        }
}
     }

}
```

Comment: It works but it also redirects even if it doesn't have a matched ID. I used else condition still nothing.

Comment: its not possible because when query match then result >0 and if condition run if not match then no if loop run check your condition and write some other code

Comment: I tried mysqli_fetch_assoc and still gets redirected even if it doesn't have matched ID.

Comment: use for each loop instead of if in while

Comment: Can you check my code I edited my question that's what I used.

Comment: I'm getting a same result.